# HTTP/2 header fields containing lists of values

Tags: http-headers, http2

In HTTP/1.1 header fields multiple values are usually separated with a comma:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, identity; q=0.5
```

But it is also possible to use multiple header fields:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Encoding: identity; q=0.5
```

Is it in HTTP/2 still possible to choose, or is there only the first option left?

I know there is special handling for the `Cookie` header field, so multiple fields with the same name are not generally forbidden: http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#CompressCookie

The `Set-Cookie` header also requires multiple fields to create multiple cookies.

Comment: As you mention, the [HTTP 2.0 draft](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-17) allows for both syntaxes in **Section 
8.1.2.5 Compressing the Cookie Header Field** for the `cookie` header in particular (though the separator used must be `;` instead of `,` in the first syntax). I don't see mention in the draft of whether the two syntaxes are (dis)allowed for other headers, so I assume that they are both supported and inherited from HTTP 1.1, where `,` is the separator used for the first syntax, per [RFC 7230 section 3.2.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.2).

Comment: Per [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265), `Set-Cookie` does not allow multiple cookies to be specified in a single header, multiple cookies must be separated into their own individual `Set-Cookie` header.  I don't see HTTP/2 overriding that rule.